# Hammerjs panend not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, hammer.js

I have used hammerjs (version: 2.0.8) pan events to move an element (span). It works fine on Chrome and Firefox. But `panend` event is not working in Firefox. only `panstart` and `panmove` events are firing.

Comment: Do you have a working example for this. I am really curious about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's known issue on [project's github](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/692). It seems that v. 2.0.1 works fine

Comment: but im using the latest 2.0.8 version. should i downgrade to fix this issue ?

Comment: It seems to be the only solution at the moment, before the patch will land. We've had a lot of problems with hammerjs in the past, so it doesn't surprise me too much.

Comment: sure, thanks for the information. Will wait for the patch :)